# Update Azure SDK 2.1 to latest version of 3.0

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

Team,

I am a beginner in Azure. I have a task to upgrade the Azure SDK from 2.1 to the latest version available. The Azure project is housed under a MVC 4.0 solution and is currently using VS 2012.

Is it mandatory to use VS 2017 professional/Enterprise edition to work further on the project.

Can i still have VS 2012 and upgrade to the lastest Azure SDK version. How to go about it ?

My AZURE project uses a worker role, Azure storage n all.. Can anyone give me the step by step upgradation steps for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can i still have VS 2012 and upgrade to the lastest Azure SDK version. How to go about it ?

The short answer is **no**. We could get the answer from this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54917).

We could know that VS 2015+ is required to install the Azure SDK 3.0

> **System Requirements**
>   Supported Operating System
>   Windows 10 , Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2016
>
> **Note: Windows 7 Home Basic is not supported.**
>
> **Required Software:**
>
> - **Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 OR**
> - **Microsoft Visual Studio Express for Web 2015 OR**
> - **Microsoft Visual Studio Community Edition 2015**
> - IIS7 or IIS10 with ASP.NET and WCF HTTP Activation, Static Content, IIS Management Console and HTTP Redirection.
> - WebDeployment Tools 2.1 or up

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Also, please can i have a step by step upgradation steps of Azure SDK in my Azure project having a worker role?

Comment: As Azure SDK 2.1 is retired, I recommand that you use the latest version of Visual Studio to use Azure SDK . But you also could get more  information about azure SDK from this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/archive-net-downloads/)

Comment: Thanks .but I would like to know how do you go about updating the worker role and the azure project with the latest SDK. Can you please let me know step by step.

Comment: You could refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-upgrade-projects-to-the-current-version-of-the-azure-tools) to get more information about how to upgrade an Azure project to the current release.